# Java file not found exception - /proc/mtprof/status: open failed:

Tags: android

Can anyone explain why this error occurs ?

I play one audio file from asset folder using media player and show some images in imageview from drawable folder.Project is build in android 4.0.3 api.

This works perfect before add admobsdk to project . now i am not able to see images in imageview . Can anyone give me solution for this ?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/mtprof/status: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/ActivityManager(  231):       at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:448)
E/ActivityManager(  231):       at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
E/ActivityManager(  231):       at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
E/ActivityManager(  231):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.mtProf(ActivityRecord.java:852)
E/ActivityManager(  231):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.windowsDrawn(ActivityRecord.java:653)
E/ActivityManager(  231):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord$Token.windowsDrawn(ActivityRecord.java:225)
E/ActivityManager(  231):       at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:6994)
E/ActivityManager(  231):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/ActivityManager(  231):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
E/ActivityManager(  231):       at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:754)
E/ActivityManager(  231): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/ActivityManager(  231):       at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
E/ActivityManager(  231):       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
E/ActivityManager(  231):       at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:432)
```

**Code**

```
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
descriptor = getAssets().openFd("test.mp3" );
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength() );
descriptor.close();
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
buttonPlay.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pause_button));
buttonPlay.setTag(getResources().getString(R.string.pause));
```

Comment: have u accidently deleted some file. If you havent closed ur IDE, check in Restore Local History.

Comment: No, i don't delete file or closed my IDE.

Comment: Check if it's not like, you are having code to set images after the line that is giving error.. and as you get error control goes to catch block and images are not set.. as normal way I guess drawable should be shown easily.. check control is reaching to the lines where you set drawable images..